# How change the format DateTime of a column in DataTable from c#

Tags: asp.net, datetime, foreach, datatable

In DataTable i have this format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM 
I want to change format to "dd.MM.yyyy"

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
      {
          dr["birth_day"]= String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}",dr["birth_day"]);
      }
```

It gave me this error:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.Couldn't store <25.04.1988> in birth_day Column.  Expected type is DateTime.

Comment: I'm sorry, this looks very obvious. You didn't give `String.Format` any text to format.

Comment: You cannot change format of data that have type as DateTime. It suppose to be some where else to get what you want. And Error is because of @DCoder said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String format needs more than one argument, one for the string, and 1-n for each variable you have in the string.

e.g.

```
dr["birth_day"]= DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}:dd.MM.yyyy",dr["birth_day"]));
```

Though i am still not sure this would give what you want

Comment: You have edited the question - is there still a question outstanding ? The dr["birth_day"] is a datetime field so it is irrelevant how it is stored inside , when you want to display it you convert it at that time.

Answer (score 2):

It's saying you have not provided and argument for the place holder {0} as in

```
dr["birth_day"]= DateTime.Parse(String.Format("{0}:dd.MM.yyyy",SomeValuethatgoesbeforethe colon));
```

However your code makes no sense at all, where's the date that's meant to be parsed?